# GPU parallelism dilemma

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu

My question is does OpenGL draw primitives parallel, or only the rastering is done that way? To put it simply if I want to draw the same primitive twice, does it render faster if I copy my vertices into a buffer twice, and just call drawarrays once, or will that result in the same rendering speed as if I only copy my vertices once, and called drawarrays twice (not counting the time it takes the CPU to call on the GPU)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the GPU and driver; a typical graphics card has a number of cores that can run the same codepath on multiple datasets. This is the classic [Single instruction, multiple data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) parallelism and the core of the parallelism of openGL.

Calling drawArrays twice doesn't help for that as the entire pipeline will be executed twice.

If you want to draw multiple copies of the same mesh in different places you would typically use [instancing](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) to change the uniforms between instances.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is draw a bezier and a b-spline curve, based on the same controlpoints. I want to do most of the calculations in the geometry shader, and pass the points in a uniform. That means that one geom.shader call is required for the bezier, and one for the b-spline. So I'm trying to decide to call the geom.shader twice, and modify a bool uniform between them, that switches the geom.shader from bezier to b-spline, or call it once, the bool placed in the VAO, switching the geom.shader. If two instances of the geom.shader run parallel then the second would be faster.

Comment: Executing the pipeline twice doesn't matter cause the vertex shader is pass through and the fragment is just showing white color. However the geom.shader is heavy (calculating bezier or b-spline curves is a lot of calculations) so it would help a lot if I could tell the GPU to run a geom.shader for a bezier while running a geom.shader for a b-spline.

Comment: @CivDav Geometry shaders are actually difficult to parallelize because the number of outputs (vertices/primitives emitted) can vary based on run-time execution. In other stages, the workflow is better defined before execution begins. Assuming static control flow in the Geometry Shader, you can assume that an implementation will try to parallelize GS invocations when such a thing makes sense. However, this is all outside the scope of any desktop rendering API.